# UITabbar stretched in iOS 10 but not 11+

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios10, uitabbar

So I've been developing my app on iOS 11 and 12 for the past few weeks, but after testing on the iOS 10.3.3 iphone 7 simulator (and real iphone 7's), I just realized that the tab bar icons look really stretched for some reason.

They look fine on all phones iOS 11+

I followed the guidelines here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

My image sizes are

@3x: 75x75
@2x: 50x50
@1x: 25x25

I've played around in storyboard and have no idea how to fix this. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out I had imbalanced tab bar item insets.

Changing from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

ended up fixing the issue. Not really sure why it doesn't work below iOS 11.